# Python Opencv módulo dnn_superres

Tags: python, opencv, cv2

Estoy intentando utilizar el módulo dnn_superres de la librería cv2 de python para dar mayor resolución a una imagen recortada. El problema es que al poner:

from cv2 import dnn_superres

No me lo coge ya que parece que el paquete opencv-contrib-python no me carga el módulo dnn_superres. He de decir que, no tengo instalado la librería opencv-python porque puede dar error con la otra que tengo (contrib es más completo). Además en los docs de opencv se indica que el módulo dnn_superres está dentro de opencv-contrib-python.

Dejo por aquí mi parte del código donde hago las importaciones:

```
from cv2 import dnn_superres
```

```
def superresolution(crop):
    """
        Función para mejorar la calidad de un crop
        - crop: es un objeto recortado de la imagen
    """
    assert crop.shape[0] > 0
    # https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/dnn_superres
    sr = dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()
    # https://github.com/Saafke/EDSR_Tensorflow/tree/master/models
    path1 = "./quality_models/edsr_model/EDSR_x2.pb"
    path2 = "./quality_models/edsr_model/EDSR_x3.pb"
    path3 = "./quality_models/edsr_model/EDSR_x4.pb"
    # https://github.com/fannymonori/TF-ESPCN/tree/master/export
    path4 = "./quality_models/espcn_model/ESPCN_x2.pb"
    path5 = "./quality_models/espcn_model/ESPCN_x3.pb"
    path6 = "./quality_models/espcn_model/ESPCN_x4.pb"
    # https://github.com/Saafke/FSRCNN_Tensorflow/tree/master/models
    path7 = "./quality_models/fsrcnn_model/FSRCNN_x2.pb"
    path8 = "./quality_models/fsrcnn_model/FSRCNN_x3.pb"
    path9 = "./quality_models/fsrcnn_model/FSRCNN_x4.pb"
    # https://github.com/fannymonori/TF-LapSRN/tree/master/export
    path10 = "./quality_models/lapsrn_model/LapSRN_x2.pb"
    path11 = "./quality_models/lapsrn_model/LapSRN_x4.pb"
    path12 = "./quality_models/lapsrn_model/LapSRN_x8.pb"
    path = path2
    model = "edsr"
    scale = 3
    sr.readModel(path)
    # ("edsr", 2)
    # ("espcn", 2)
    # ("fsrcnn", 2)
    # ("lapsrn", 2)
    sr.setModel(model, scale)
    result = sr.upsample(crop)
    # print(sr.getAlgorithm())
    return result
```

Como se puede ver normalmente el vscode pone un color cuando la coge, pero no es el caso. Cabe destacar que el código se ejecuta perfectamente pero al terminar con un tipo de modelo la imagen se ve igual sin ningún tipo de mejora.

Estoy usando Windows 10 (64bits), Python 3.9.12 y la librería opencv-contrib-python==4.5.5.64

Comment: Por favor, evita subir capturas o fotos de tu pantalla mostrando texto. Además de que nosotros podríamos no tener ganas (ni tiempo) de ponernos a transcribir tu código, existen otros motivos enumerados aquí: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880

Comment: En vez de poner el código como imagen añade en texto plano.

Comment: Buenas, era para que se viera bien que no me coge el módulo dnn_superres.

Comment: Si le hiciste correctamente `pip install opencv-contrib-python` y tu versión de python es >=3.6. Entonces tendrás mal configuradas las variables de entorno o has puesto mal el entorno virtual.